# (oh-my-)zsh's filename completion changes current font

Tags: fonts, zsh

I have just installed the (awesome) oh-my-zsh package to customize my zsh prompt, but I've hit this weird problem:

If I use autocompletion on a command name (e.g. `sou<TAB>` -> `source`), everything works as intended.  However, if I use autocompletion on a *file* name (e.g. `source .zshr<TAB>` -> `source .zshrc`), the font changes to grey bold for the whole command.  I do use bold in my `PROMPT` as well as colors, but not gray, so I don't know where that color code comes from; also the fact that it only happens when completing a file name puzzles me.

Here are my `PROMPT` and `RPROMPT` (inspired from Steve Losh's `prose` theme).

```
PROMPT='
%B%F{208}%n%{$reset_color%}%{$fg_bold[white]%}@%B%F{039}$(box_name)
%{$reset_color%}:%{$fg_bold[green]%}${PWD/#$HOME/~}%{$reset_color%}
$(hg_prompt_info)$(git_prompt_info)
$(virtualenv_info)$(prompt_char) '

RPROMPT='${return_status}%{$reset_color%}[%t]'
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, the solution was rather simple: color&weight changes introduces by %B and %F must be closed by %b and %f, not by $reset_color... that's all.

Answer (score 0):

Reset the colors just before closing the single quotes on both prompts; or you can also use `%{^[[0m%}` escape sequence. Note that `^[` is one character being the control-escape you can type it by first holding control and typing v then release and hit the escape key once.